# Get all email address of an account in Outlook 2007 in C# or vb

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I am developing an Outlook add-in in VB. I want all the registered email addresses in  an Outlook account. I wrote some code which gives me only the current or default mail ID from the user but I want all email ID's that are registered in the Outlook account settings.

```
UserName = Me.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.CurrentUser.Address
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access global Address using following code and for more ref [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184654%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

```
Outlook.AddressList gal = Application.Session.GetGlobalAddressList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, Sandeep wants the accounts, not the address book.

The Outlook Application object has an [Accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176420%28v=office.12%29.aspx) collection. Iterate through that to get all `the accounts available for the current profile`.